# Pandas create list of of subset of column names except one

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list-comprehension

I can create a list of columns names from my df that contain a specified string as such:

`[col for col in clean_data.columns if '9am' in col]`

I have found plenty of recipes that answer: how to retrieve all column names except one.

What I want is all columns containing '9am' except one (that also contains '9am').

The one I wish to exclude is: 'relative_humidity_9am'

Yes I can just delete it, but I was trying to retrieve all of the '9am' columns except the one above in a single step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```py
[col for col in clean_data.columns if '9am' in col and col != 'relative_humidity_9am']
```